# Filter array of arrays in purescript

Tags: purescript

Doing this in `psci`:

```
> filter (\[a,b] -> a > 1) [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

results in a compile error:

```
A case expression could not be determined to cover all inputs.
```

due to `[a,b]` possibly failing to match, which makes sense.

I know I can do this:

```
> :p
… let f [a, b] = a > 1
…     f _ = false
…
> filter f [[1,2],[3,4]]
[[3,4]]
```

but this is quite long for doing simple filters in `psci` repl. Is there a solution that involves less typing (including not using `Array`, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unsafePartial`:

```
> import Prelude
> import Data.Array
> import Partial.Unsafe
> filter (unsafePartial \[a,b] -> a > 1) [[1,2],[3,4]]
[[3,4]]
```

I wouldn't recommend doing so outside of the REPL though, unless you've pre-sanitised the input and you're 100% sure the pattern match isn't partial!

Comment: Thanks gb., this makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that

> (including not using Array, etc.)?

means you could use tuples, or records, instead of nested arrays. Their structure is much easier to pattern match / deconstruct, e.g.:

```
filter (\(Tuple a b) -> a > 1) [ Tuple 1 2, Tuple 3 4 ]
```

As far as I know, PureScript does not support syntax for single-line case expressions (like `case arr of { [a,b] -> a > 1; _ -> false }`).
If you need to use arrays, I think your multi-line solution is better than something like:

```
filter (\arr -> fromMaybe false (map (\a -> a > 1) (head arr))) [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Fits into one line, but does not read very well...